# ambari_agent restart cause ansible crash

Tags: linux, ansible, ambari, hdp

we have big-data Hadoop cluster based on horton-works HDP version 2.6.4 and ambari 2.6.1 version

all machines are with RHEL 7.2 version

in our cluster we have more then 540 machines and on all machines we have ambari-agent that communicate with ambari server , ( Ambari server is installed only on one machine ) while ambari-agent installed on all machines

until using ansible everything was good ,  when we do ambari-agent upgrade and ambari-agent restart

but recently we start to use ansible ( ansible-playbook ) in order to automate the installation

and ansible is running on all machines

so when task do the ambari-agent restart , then imminently  we notice that ansible execution stooped and killed

after some investigation we saw that ambari agent is using the following ports

```
url_port = 8440
secured_url_port = 8441
ping_port = 8670
```

but I not see that any ansible process used above ports , so we not think its related

but the basic issue is clear

when ansible task doing on remote machine - ambari-agent restart , then its caused ansible interrupt and ansible killed

ambari-agent configuration looks like this

```
[server]
hostname = datanode02.gtfactory.com
url_port = 8440
secured_url_port = 8441
connect_retry_delay = 10
max_reconnect_retry_delay = 30

[agent]
logdir = /var/log/ambari-agent
piddir = /var/run/ambari-agent
prefix = /var/lib/ambari-agent/data
loglevel = INFO
data_cleanup_interval = 86400
data_cleanup_max_age = 2592000
data_cleanup_max_size_mb = 100
ping_port = 8670
cache_dir = /var/lib/ambari-agent/cache
tolerate_download_failures = true
run_as_user = root
parallel_execution = 0
alert_grace_period = 5
status_command_timeout = 5
alert_kinit_timeout = 14400000
system_resource_overrides = /etc/resource_overrides

[security]
keysdir = /var/lib/ambari-agent/keys
server_crt = ca.crt
passphrase_env_var_name = AMBARI_PASSPHRASE
ssl_verify_cert = 0
credential_lib_dir = /var/lib/ambari-agent/cred/lib
credential_conf_dir = /var/lib/ambari-agent/cred/conf
credential_shell_cmd = org.apache.hadoop.security.alias.CredentialShell

[network]
use_system_proxy_settings = true

[services]
pidlookuppath = /var/run/

[heartbeat]
state_interval_seconds = 60
dirs = /etc/hadoop,/etc/hadoop/conf,/etc/hbase,/etc/hcatalog,/etc/hive,/etc/oozie,
        /etc/sqoop,
        /var/run/hadoop,/var/run/zookeeper,/var/run/hbase,/var/run/templeton,/var/run/oozie,
        /var/log/hadoop,/var/log/zookeeper,/var/log/hbase,/var/run/templeton,/var/log/hive
log_lines_count = 300
idle_interval_min = 1
idle_interval_max = 10

[logging]
syslog_enabled = 0
```

**for now we are thinking about the following:**

maybe ansible crash because TLSv1 is restricted ( Transport Layer Security ) ,  the default is that ambari-agent connects to TLSv1

so we think to set `force_https_protocol=PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2`  in ambari agent configuration , but this is only assumption

**our suggestion and the new conf that maybe can help?**

```
[security]
force_https_protocol=PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2     <------ the new update
keysdir = /var/lib/ambari-agent/keys
server_crt = ca.crt
passphrase_env_var_name = AMBARI_PASSPHRASE
ssl_verify_cert = 0
credential_lib_dir = /var/lib/ambari-agent/cred/lib
credential_conf_dir = /var/lib/ambari-agent/cred/conf
credential_shell_cmd = org.apache.hadoop.security.alias.CredentialShell
```